# Quick Launch links inside my site template will keep referencing the original site, when I create a new subsite based on the site templete

Tags: 2013, site-collection, navigation, site-template, quick-launch

I am facing a problem inside my Sharepoint Server 2013 enterprise:

1. I have a Team sub-site, which have the following Quick Launch links:-

[image]

2. Now I save this site as template.
3. Then I create a new sub-site based on the template.

But the problem is that inside the new sub-site the "Home" link will still be referencing the original sub-site which I saved as template,, while for the other links; project documents, action, risk & site content they will be referencing the new sub-site which is valid..

Can anyone advice how I can fix this? So the Home link will be referencing the newly created sub-site rather than referencing the original sub-site which I saved as template?  And could the problem be that I have manually edited the original sub-site Home link in the past?